# Apache: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wished to block requests like `http://anything.com/something.php?hack_attempt=select *`  from users.

For this I do in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]
```

The problem is that this rule hits also `http://anything.com/update.php`
As I know `%{QUERY_STRING}` should contain only get params string after `?` , but it hits the URI.
Can anyone advice where the problem can be?

UPDATE: full rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).*                                [NC,OR]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\.|\*|;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*                 [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/ban_url/                                                           [NC,OR]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|insert|cast|set|declare|drop).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\?.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=400,L]
</IfModule>
```

if I uncomment

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]
```

then Apache will block [www.anything.com/update.php](http://www.anything.com/update.php)
but it should block only [www.anything.com/something.php?param=update](http://www.anything.com/something.php?param=update)

UPDATE 2: full conf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).*                                [NC,OR]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\.|\*|;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*                 [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/ban_url/                                                           [NC,OR]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|insert|cast|set|declare|drop).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\?.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=400,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*www\.zip*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*backup\.zip*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*public_html\.zip*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.tar\.gz*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*administrator*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*admin\.php*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*admin/index\.php*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*elrekt\.php*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*_adminer*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*accesson*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*agentui*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*trackback*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-login*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*router\.php*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*AspCms_AdminAdd*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*public/js/wind*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*include/calendar/calendar-cn*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*app-ads*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*vendor/phpunit/*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*utility/*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*blackhat*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*data/admin/allowurl*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*js/varien*                                                           [NC,OR] #magento
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*js/mage*                                                           [NC,OR] #magento
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*magento_version*                                                           [NC,OR] #magento
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*db_z\.php*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*functions\.php*                                                           [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*lottery-index*                                                           [NC]

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=400,L]


</IfModule>
```

this conf file is applied in site conf like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Include /var/www/url_blacklist.conf
        ServerName ...
        DocumentRoot ...
        ErrorLog ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please post your `RewriteRule` and be more specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: @AmitVerma updated

Comment: @MykolaMykolayovichDolynskyi, is the string `hack_attempt=` is a sample one of a real string in your query string(if not then please do mention whatever could be there with samples)? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 not real, I just want to search for any forbidden words which are only in get params (after ? sign), but in real it also finds them in URI also. I can not use sample as I don`t know which kind of attack robots will deploy next time

Comment: _“UPDATE: full rule”_ - is this your full rewrite configuration now, or are you doing other stuff as well? What you say is happening, can’t be explained by what you have shown so far, and a test tool like https://htaccess.madewithlove.be agrees.

Comment: @CBroe full rule, but not full .htaccess. Anyhow as I explained there is commented line **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update).* [NC]** if I uncomment it rule hits URL **www.anything.com/update.php** this should not be, it must hit **www.anything.com/anythingelse.php?somethin=update** and tool you provided the link to (thanks) confirms it should work like I say but in fact behaves like QUERY_STRING is REQUEST_URI+QUERY_STRING

Comment: Well show us the full .htaccess then – something else inside of it appears to be interfering with what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @BCore like what? Updated post above

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to block/forbid all those requests which have `select *` in their query string along with their uri doesn't have `update.php` requested, if this is the case could you please try following once. These conditions are written as per requested conditions only, you could try to test it alone and then could try to merge them with your existing conditions too.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} select \* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=301,F]
```

Comment: like that, I wish to redirect to 301 any request which have SQL expressions only in get params. At same time I need to allow ULRs like /update.php and so on (but QUERY_STRING hits URL also, I thought it should only include get params only)

Comment: @MykolaMykolayovichDolynskyi, looks like your conditions like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-* ` then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*www\.zip*` having an issue here, you did not put `OR` condition there so all are considered as an AND condition which can't be the case by seeing your regex(which isn't looking ok to me since everything is checking that it `^` starts from), kindly try to put `OR` condition once there?

Comment: the [NC,OR] seems to be everywhere, may be have not scrolled code frame to right?

Comment: @MykolaMykolayovichDolynskyi, sorry usually conditions wouldn't have many spaces so I haven't scrolled right to it.